# RestTemplate: Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate with custom HttpClient. My request is getting redirected to S3 but somehow it is carrying Authorization header along with it after redirection.
Httpclient is configured to use LaxRedirectStrategy, cookies are ignored.
Is there a way how to fix this issue or any insight?